# Como fazer replace na ultima aparição de um caractere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um loop que monta strings nesse formato:

```
var Sabor[0] = "Mussarela, Calabresa, Cebola";
var Sabor[1] = "Mussarela, Presunto, Calabresa, Tomate, Ovos, Pimentão, Cebola";
```

Mas gostaria de fazer um replace na **última** virgula por um " e".

Como faço isso?

A principio poderia ser com replace, mas ai vai o codigo do loop se alguem tiver outra ideia.

```
    function popularSabores(ClasseDiv, i) {
        $(ClasseDiv.toString()).append("<p class='sabor_" + Id + "'>" + Sabor + "</p><p class='ingredientes_" + Id + "'></p>");

        $.each(IngredientesArray, function (e, Ingredientes) {
            var Ingrediente = Cardapio.Pizza[i].Ingredientes[e].Ingrediente;
            if (e > 0) {
                IngredientesString += ", ";
            }
            IngredientesString += Ingrediente;
        });

        $(".ingredientes_" + Id + "").append(IngredientesString);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com Regex dá pra fazer assim:

```
var str = "Mussarela, Presunto, Calabresa, Tomate, Ovos, Pimentão, Cebola";
str = str.replace(/(.*), (.*)/, '$1 e $2');
console.log(str); // "Mussarela, Presunto, Calabresa, Tomate, Ovos, Pimentão e Cebola"
```

A expressão regular usada separa o string em duas partes, tudo até a última vírgula + espaço, e tudo após esse último espaço. Na substituição, essas duas partes são referenciadas por `$1` e `$2` respectivamente.

Outra maneira é transformando em array e reconstituindo:

```
var str = "Mussarela, Presunto, Calabresa, Tomate, Ovos, Pimentão, Cebola";
var arr = str.split(', ');
var ultimo = arr.pop();
str = arr.join(', ') + ' e ' + ultimo;
```

E na verdade a maneira mais "tradicional" é a da [resposta do @Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17629/74), que usa apenas operações de strings, extraindo e concatenando substrings com base na posição da última vírgula (que pode ser obtida via `String.lastIndexOf`).

Comment: Perfeito! Pra questão de aprendizado, como funciona esse replace? Não entendi esses caracteres em volta da virgula e do 'e'.

Comment: Incluí uma breve explicação, veja se deu pra entender. Qualquer coisa pergunte que eu esclareço.

Comment: O que nessa expressão define que é a última virgula?

Comment: É que o `.*` inclui qualquer coisa, incluindo vírgulas. Então quando você diz `.*,` (qualquer coisa seguida de vírgula), você vai sempre cair na última.

Comment: Se você olhar a sugestão do @abfurlan, funciona com o mesmo princípio, e a expressão regular dele ficou mais simples: vírgula seguida de qualquer coisa exceto vírgula só ocorre na última.

Answer (score 6):

Pode ser feito desta maneira:

```
var x = 'a,b,c';
var pos = x.lastIndexOf(',');
x = x.substring(0,pos)+' e '+x.substring(pos+1);
```

Onde o **pos** é a posição em que a ultima , se encontra, ele pega a `string` a frente da virgula, coloca na variável **x**, concatena com ' e ' e depois coloca o restante da `string`.

Comment: Gostei, com a sua resposta acho que todas as opções estão documentadas aqui! +1

Comment: Eu estava escrevendo algo um pouco mais elaborado porém nessa mesma linha de raciocínio baseado em mais uma solução do [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/substr_replace). Seguem também um [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/8gBys). E eu imagino ser uma solução mais eficaz pois resolve um problema de strings com funções de string. Apesar de ser possível parafusar com um martelo, não é certo fazê-lo (sem menosprezo as soluções baseadas em arrays ou RegExp).

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer:

```
var str = 'Mussarela, Calabresa, Cebola';
str = str.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,' e'+'$1');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Seu exemplo lá na pergunta do checkbox tava excelente, apagou pq? Ia comentar, o sistema não deixou... fiz um snapshot antes de fazer F5 :P

Comment: @brasofilo Estava invertendo a seleção qdo selecionava algum check antes de clicar no botão, vou consertar depois, valew